# MapReduce - code written in configure is not reachable

Tags: mapreduce

I wanted to move some files to the input folder and tried the required code by placing it in configure() method (I had to use Old mapred API, due to some constraints i have).
But, some how the code in configure is not being executed.

I have achieved my requirement though in other better way. Though this is a stupid idea, I wanted to know why it is not being executed. I have checked the job tracker and all variables got the right values

Code:

in main:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String date = sdf.format(new Date());

if(args[3].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("net")){

            imgInpPath = "/user/mapreduce/output/net/"+date+"/";
            inputDir = inputDir+"net/";
        }
conf.set("imgInpPath", imgInpPath);
conf.set("inputDir", inputDir);

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf,inputDir);
```

in configure()

```
inputPath = conf.get("inputDir");
Path inputImgPath = new Path(conf.get("imgInpPath"));

Configuration config = new Configuration();
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(config);
inputImgPath    = fileSystem.makeQualified(inputImgPath);

FileStatus[] status = fileSystem.listStatus(inputImgPath, new PathFilter(){
@Override
public boolean accept(Path name) {
return name.getName().contains("part");
}});

for(int i=0; i <status.length;i++)
{
    Path inpPath = status[i].getPath();
    FileUtil.copy(fileSystem, inpPath, fileSystem, new Path(inputPath), true , conf);
}
```

As i said, required thing is achieved in other way. But, I wanted to know, why this is not being performed, irrespective of the requirement.

Comment: Where do you allocate the job object? Be aware of the fact that job takes a deep copy of the configuration. If you modify the configuration afterwards it has no effect..

Comment: This code is with Old mapred api. and, JobConf has been created before the block i showed. Its been written properly.. The job is working on the input path properly, but ignoring the code in configure..